# im getting a node connetion error using chomedriver, and selenium

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver, bad-gateway

im a little new to coding and stuff but i keep getting this error trying to use chromedriver, and the website is coming up with a 502 error (bad gateway)

I've downloaded pywin32, checked for the line "resource_path" and there aren't any, instead there are executable paths, and i haven't found any fix at all on the internet.

```
[15:18:59.410] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1056 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
```

Answer (score 0):

i found a fix!! first download [this chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-switcher/aedikcfpfonanffanecfolneiaoakmlc?hl=en#:%7E:text=User%2DAgent%20Switcher%20is%20a,add%20your%20own%20user%2Dagents) then click the extension, and set the user-agent to "Chrome on Mac"

also open cmd and type:

```
pip install pywin32
```